# What do you mean by the subspace spanned by the matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What do you mean by the subspace spanned by the matrices $\{1,A,A^2,\dots,A^n\}$ where A is and $n\times n$ real or complex matrix.

Comment: If i consider the zero matrix i am getting the subspace spanned by $\{1\}$.. what about the remaining cases.. and What about the dimensions...

Answer (score 4):

The set of all linear combinations
$$
c_{0} 1 + c_{1} A + \dots + c_{n} A^{n},
$$
where the $c_{i}$ are possibly in the same field as the coefficients of $A$.

---

As to the dimension, it equals the degree of the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Comment: I think you should sat $I$ instaed of $1$.

Comment: OP used $1$, so I went along...

Comment: so, he should also use $I$ .. :)

Comment: To me, it is the unity in a ring, so $1$ is appropriate. But with my first-year students I use $I$, or even $I_{n}$, lest I sound too abstract.

Comment: My last comment was a joke, I did not notice op also use it, if it is clear for op, of course no problem as $1$ can be used for groups ,rings ...

Comment: Got it! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

well, All matrices in the form $$c_0I+c_1A+.. +c_nA^n$$  where $c_i \in F$. (It is subspace as set of all matrices are vector space.)

Answer (score 1):

This answer just adds a small point which seems not to have been mentioned yet.  As already stated, the subspace spanned by the matrices is the set of all linear combinations of the matrices.

By the Cauchy-Hamilton Theorem, the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ satisfies its own characteristic polynomial, which has degree $n$.  That is,
$$\lambda_0I+\lambda_1A+\cdots+\lambda_nA^n={\bf0}\ .$$
Therefore the $n+1$ matrices you have given must be linearly dependent, and **the dimension of the subspace is $n$ or less**.

The exact dimension will be the degree of the minimal polynomial of $A$, as mentioned elsewhere.